# Restricting replyTo Field in SMTP (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

Is it possible to restrict the user to reply to a mail sent via SMTP server?
I have tried using obsolete before the method name but still reply mail could not be blocked

```
void sendmail()

    {
            string to = "abc@xyz.com";
            string from = "def@abc.com";
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
            message.Body = @"Test"
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    }
```

above is the sample code.

Comment: You want to stop the user from being able to reply to the email? So if I got your email right now into my Outlook you want my reply button to be disabled for this mail?

Comment: I want to block the replyto field in the outlook box

Comment: Do we have anyother possibilities to achieve this scenario? Like setting restrictions

Comment: You'd need direct access to their PC and I guess you'd have to write an addon to achieve this. I've never seen it available as a group policy and you certainly can't override it with a setting in the email itself. The better questions here is WHY do you want to disable the reply to field? It seems rather odd.

Comment: For any case the member in the To field should not reply. say if I'm a company and generating an automatic mail. I can only notify "This is an automatic mail please do not reply" to him. But still he can reply. Can we go beyond with any other chances?

Comment: What you've described is already the only option. You would normally send the reply from an address like `donotreply@mycompany.com` to make it obvious and include a message in the body. The user will always have the ability to reply if they want to.

Comment: If you are using exchange or an SMTP you have full control over, just disable the ability of the account to receive emails. As others have said, you can't stop somebody from replying to an email without direct access, so instead block the ability to receive emails to your sending account.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, it is impractical/impossible (depending on level of access to their computers) to prevent a user replying to an email. However, you can prevent an exchange email account from receiving emails by applying delivery restrictions - telling the account to only receive emails from itself:

> On the server running Exchange start "Active Directory Users and Computers"
>   Find the account.
>
> Double click the account to open its properties (or right click and select "Properties")
>
> On the "Exchange General" tab, click [Delivery Restrictions...].
>
> Under "Message restrictions" check "From authenticated users only". Then select the radio button "Only from" and add the user account. It is important that you add a user account here otherwise Exchange will accept email from any authenticated user.
>
> Click [OK] to close the "Delivery Restrictions" dialog and [OK] again to close the account properties dialog.

Using this method, to any other user it will look like the account does not exist and they will receive delivery failed messages.

This an other methods are detailed here: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/msexchange/exch_howto_disable_delivery.htm